# Display an image through page.tpl.php only on front page

Tags: 7, theming, media

I want to display an image only on front page through page.tpl.php... However i am not sure about the syntax or where i am going wrong as the code that i type in leads me to en error (syntax error)...here's the code:

```
<?php  if (drupal_is_front_page())
    {
        <div id ="join">
           <a href="/node/38"><img src="/sites/all/themes/ypwb/joinb.png"></a>
        </div>
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need `?>` after the opening parenthesis and `<?php` before the closing parenthesis. This is so-called embedding HTML in a PHP page.

Comment: @Sithu you can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `?>` after the opening parenthesis and `<?php` before the closing parenthesis. This is so-called embedding HTML among PHP coding.

Most likely, you can use parenthesis, but you can see the default theme Bartik uses [the alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (:).

```
<?php if (drupal_is_front_page()): ?>
    <div id ="join">
       <a href="<?php echo drupal_get_path_alias('node/38'); ?>">
         <img src="<?php echo drupal_get_path('theme', 'ypwb').'/joinb.png'; ?>">
       </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You could use [page--front.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/732168) as subhojit777 suggested, whereas you are right to use [drupal_is_front_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7).

As a side note, you should use [drupal_get_path_alias()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) for your node path and [drupal_get_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) for your image path.

Comment: Extra points if using l() and theme_image() :)

Comment: @DavidThomas, you are right.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than editing in `page.tpl.php` which applies on all pages, you should create a template file called `page--front.tpl.php` and add image there if you want to display the image only in front page.

**EDIT**

For more theme hook suggestions refer this [page](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

Comment: OP is right to use `drupal_is_front_page()`. This is a syntax error only.

Comment: kewal is asking to add image ONLY on front page.. may be he is doing wrong in syntax, but I like best practices in Drupal and the template hook I suggested is an example of that :)

Comment: Yes, the question title sounds like what you said. But if you read the question body carefully, you will see what the actual problem he is facing.